# Maven: Issue while exculding Nested Dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

I have Project A which dependes on Project B which dependes further of Project C which further depend on D
A-> B -> C-> D

First Project B is build using maven shade plugin, 
So B jar has dependency of C and D both

Now when I include Project B in A, A already have dependency of D with different Version. 
When I am excluding 
I excluded D from Project B. But nothing happens.

In Project A pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>sample.ProjectD</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-D from Project-B -->
          <artifactId>Project-D</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>



 mvn dependecy:tree doesnt show that it has C in its path or D in its path after exclude. 
    But within scala class, I am able to use classes from package D. 

    When I open the Jar of B, I can see C and D as classPaths in B. Is it anything to do be maven-shade ?
```

My Maven Pom with build tag:

```
<build>
    <finalName>dp-experiment</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
                            <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                            <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>true</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

What I am able to do in project A pom?
exclude jar of C from B

What I am not able to do ?
exclude jar of any dependency within C or inner dependency of dependency inside B.

Comment: do all 4 of your projects containt this version?

    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

Comment: you mean C and D should be of version1.0 ? No they are not. Well C is of version 1.2 and D is version 1.0 within C.

Comment: B and A have the same version number for D in their pom.xml?

Comment: No I want A to have different version of D. That is why I want to exclude from B. I want A to have 1.1 snapshot of D.

Comment: I created a fresh project to check the issue. In A there is one dependency i.e of B with 2 exclusions of C and D.  Then I created a class and tried using a class of D. And I could use it. So that means D is not excluded.

Comment: but if you're reffering in A on another version of D than your're reffering in B (see dependencies) this could be the problem. Also if you are using e.g. org.xyz v1.1 in A and org.xyz v2.0 in B,C or D (the version numbers are fantasy numbers) you will run into a version conflict. If there's no other way around your dependency hell, then you might consider OSGI as an option.

Comment: But that is why I am excluding D from B so as not to run in version conflict.

Comment: You are referencing an uber jar created by Shade. This jar contains all dependencies already.

Comment: So if B is a uber jar and I am importing in A,  I can still exlcude D right ? Can u explain more in detail ?